# Adding point to Polyline on click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to listen for a click event on a Polyline, so that there is a point added where the polyline was clicked.  Though I am unsure of how I would determine the location in the points[] to add the new point.

My initial solution was to have an array of points.  Then, iterate through the points and add a new polyline for each 2 points.  Then have each polyline listen for a click, and I know I have to add the point after the first point for that line.

Are there any ways to figure out where on the polyline it was clicked?

Comment: To clarify: do you want to draw the point at the clicked position or at the vertices of the clicked segment?

Comment: Something like [this example](http://www.wolfpil.de/v3/snapable-lines.html) by [Wolfgang Pichler](http://www.wolfpil.de/)?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that @geocodezip